# How to use functions return in another function in C?

Tags: c, function

This function i have returns the `billType` and I want to use this `billType` in my main function.

```
int bill()
{
    int billType;
    printf("Enter bill type (1=utilities, 2=internet) : ");
    scanf("%d",&billType);
    return billType;
}
```

here main function:

```
int main()
{
    int discount;

    bill();

    if(billType == 1)
    {
        int choice;
        printf("\nEnter 1=TNB or 2=SYABAS: ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);

        if(choice == 1)
        {
            discount= 0.05;
        }

        else if(choice == 2)
        {
            discount= 0.10;
        }
    }

    if(billType == 2)
    {
        int choice;
        printf("\nEnter 1=DIGI, 2=UNIFI or 3=MAXIS FIBRE : ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);

        discount = 0.05;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will want to assign the return value to a variable for later use.

You should change

```
bill();
```

to

```
int billType = bill();
```

Also it looks weird to assign small values such as `0.10` and `0.05` to `int discount;` because they will be truncated to zero. Consider using another type (for example, `double`) or remove the meaningless lines (because `discount` is not read).